# Array SAM Scala not allowed

Tags: scala, syntax, scala-2.11, single-abstract-method

It seems you can not initialize an Array with a SAM syntax. When I try the following...

```
trait A {
  def num(): Int
}

trait B extends A

trait C extends A

val nums: Array[A] = Array(() => 5)
```

I get the following error...

```
<console>:12: error: type mismatch;
 found   : () => Int
 required: A
       val nums: Array[A] = Array(() => 5)
```

Is this behavior expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works in Scala 2.12, but SAM support in Scala 2.11 is incomplete (that's why it's under `-Xexperimental`). For Scala 2.11 you can use

```
Array[A](() => 5)
```

as a workaround.